# How to match dates then copy respective data from one spreadsheet to another if the dates are repeated but the data is unique?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search a reporting spreadsheet(1) for a date and then search for that date in a data source spreadsheet(2). Once found, I would like to copy and paste data (from the same row as the date in (2)) into the corresponding date in the reporting spreadsheet(1).

However, there are multiple repetitions of each date (in both 1 and 2) but all the data corresponding to respective dates (in spreadsheet 2) is unique, so I would like to search for a matching date and then copy and paste the data to the corresponding row, but then not use this same row again, and move on to the next match...

Currently, my macro copies data from (2) to (1) according to matching date, but if there are 6 repetitions of the date, only the 6th match of the dates (with corresponding data) is used for all rows.

```
Sub Macroturnip()
'
' Macroturnip Macro
'

Dim Row As Double 'row is the row variable for the destination spreadsheet
Dim i As Date
Dim x As Long 'x is the row variable for the source spreadsheet


For Row = 1 To 825

    i = Sheets("1").Cells(Row, 1)

      If i <> DateSerial(1900, 1, 0) Then
        'DateSerial(1900, 1, 0) --> this is the default for no data in the field, i.e. i want to skip these

            For x = 1 To 450

                If Sheets("2").Cells(x, 2) = Sheets("1").Cells(Row, 1) Then
                Sheets("2").Select
                Cells(x, 1).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("1").Select
                Cells(Row, 2).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

                End If

            Next x



     End If



Next Row


End Sub
```

Comment: Can I add a column which is a count of each date so that will identify them as unique? My issue would be implementing a loop with this @alowflyingpig

Comment: Just want clarity on your wanted outcome - Search Reporting(Sht) for a date and match that date on Source(Sht), if found, copy entire(?) row from Source(Sht) to Reporting(Sht). Is this right? If so what col are the dates in?

Comment: @alowflyingpig no- if match, i dont want to copy the entire column, instead, I want to copy a single cell which is the same row as the matched date from Source(Sht) to a cell in the same row as the corresponding date in the Reporting(Sht).

Comment: what cols are your data in? and what col is the data you want copied in and copied to?

Comment: @alowflyingpig I want data copied from sheet 2 column 1 to sheet 1 column 2

Comment: @alowflyingpig dates are in sheet 1 column 1 sheet 2 column 2